# Merging documents with itextsharp

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I am not experienced with `iTextSharp` and have this need:

I have generated 2 PDFs:

- a small PDF (i.e. size A6) of one page containing 1 background image and some text in various format (paragraph, chunks, etc), some barcode some rectancles... But nothing more (no forms etc). The pdf is generated to a memory stream.
- a bigger one (i.e. size A3). I want to "copy" or embed the little pdf to the bigger in a fixed position.

**How can I merge them?** All examples I found use `PDFReader`, but I am not able to use it on a memory stream and I dont' like to save intermediate PDF to disk.

Comment: A `PdfReader` can absolutely bind to a stream although I'd recommend calling `ToArray()` on your `MemoryStream` and just passing in your raw bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially want to stamp a page from one document somewhere onto the bigger page of another one.

This is a task for a `PdfStamper`.

- Open the document with the small page in a `PdfReader readerA`
- Open the document with the big page in a `PdfReader readerB`
- Create a `PdfStamper stamperB` for `readerB`
- Import the page from `readerA` using `stamperB.GetImportedPage`
- Add this imported page object to the exisiting target page using `stamperB.OverContent.AddTemplate`; this method allows to supply positioning coordinates
- close the `stamperB`, then the readers